# smallrye-quarkus validation can be disabled when requests has an expired jwt token on @PermitAll method?

Tags: java, quarkus, smallrye

when the header data contains an Authorization entry with an expired jwt token, smallrye validates it showing an exception info because of token expiration.

being a `@PermitAll` resource it should not consider the jwt to let the request being called.

Configuring the `quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false` has no effect, is there anyway to disable this validation without the use of filters?